# Can I write an if statement within a Javascript object when setting an attribute?

Tags: javascript

Setting attributeTwo using an if statement. What is the correct way to do this?

```
var testBoolean = true;

var object = {
  attributeOne: "attributeOne",
  attributeTwo: if (testBoolean) { "attributeTwo" } else { "attributeTwoToo" },
}
```

Comment: use short hand if: (attributeTwo: (true ? some_value : some_other_value);

Comment: @Rooster—that would be the [conditional operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12), also called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). :-)

Comment: @RobG short hand if is a much better and easier to remember name ;-P

Comment: No problemwith that, but in a technical forum it's good to include the appropriate technical term. :-)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

No, however you can use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var testBoolean = true;

var object = {
  attributeOne: "attributeOne",
  attributeTwo: testBoolean ? "attributeTwo" : "attributeTwoToo"
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use an if statement, if it is within a immediately invoked function.

```
var x = {
  y: (function(){
       if (true) return 'somevalue';
     }())
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use an if statement directly, but you can use [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (aka conditional operator) which behaves the way you want.  Here is how it would look:

```
var testBoolean = true;

var object = {
  attributeOne: "attributeOne",
  attributeTwo: testBoolean ? "attributeTwo" : "attributeTwoToo"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also do by this method

```
var testBoolean = true;

var object = {
  attributeOne: "attributeOne"
}
```

> 1

```
if(testBoolean){
   object.attributeTwo = "attributeTwo"
}else{
   object.attributeTwo = "attributeTwoToo"
}
```

> 2

```
object.attributeTwo = testBoolean ? "attributeTwo" : "attributeTwoToo"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can put a conditional statement like this way, where conditional statement also works for object's key also.

```js
let inbox = true;
let assign = {...(inbox ? {assign_to: 2} : {})};
console.log("assign", assign);

inbox = false;
assign = {...(inbox ? {assign_to: 2} : {})};
console.log("assign", assign);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old but i haven't seen anyone give this answer so i'll just drop this here, you can actually pass a function inside the property of your object like this:

```js
var testBoolean = true;

const genericFunc = (testBoolean) => {
  if(testBoolean !== true){
    return 'False'
  }else {
    return 'True'
  } 
}

var object = {
  attributeOne: "attributeOne",
  attributeTwo: genericFunc(testBoolean),
}

console.log('Object',object)
```

As long as the function you pass actually has a return statement, it'll work!

Answer (score 0):

To add a value conditionally in an object you can do something like this

```
const condition = true;
var obj = {
    key: condition ? value1 : value2
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Indeed you can but why don't you do the conditional statement before assigning it to object attribute. The code would be nicer.

Comment: Should be a comment not an answer