# if statement inside object Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting my data from localestorage and saving to my **personalInfo** object, later i want to send this object to my API, but for some cases my *underageChildInfo* and *beneficiaryInfo* wont exist and i get error. how can i remove my array from this object if it doesnt exist in localestorage?

```
this.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('policy'));       

get info(): any {
         return this.personalInfo = {
            personalInfoId: 0,
            insurerInfo: {
               firstName:  this.data.calculatorInfo.name,
               lastName : this.data.calculatorInfo.surname,
               phoneNumber: this.data.contactInfo.phone,
               email: this.data.contactInfo.email
            },
            underageChildInfo: this.data.underageChildInfo.map(i =>
              ({
              firstName: i.name,
              lastName: i.surname,
              birthDate: i.birthDate
            })),
            beneficiaryInfo:
            this.data.beneficiaryInfo.map(i =>({
              firstName: i.name,
              lastName: i.surname
            }))
          }
       }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.info);
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Built the object one step at a time: `const result = { ... }; if (this.data.beneficiaryInfo) { ... }; ...`

Comment: `underageChildInfo: this.data.underageChildInfo?.map(...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Optional Chaining for this. Change your code to:

```
this.data.beneficiaryInfo?.map(i =>({
    firstName: i.name,
    lastName: i.surname
}))
```

By adding the '?' immediately behind 'beneficiaryInfo' JS will first check if beneficiaryInfo exists before executing the map function.

Ofcourse there are a 1.000 other ways to accomplish this. But this would be the simplest. Does it help?

[MDN Reference for Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following.

```
this.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('policy'));       

get info(): any {
     let keys:Array<any> = Object.keys(this.data);
     let underageChildInfo = keys.indexOf(underageChildInfo);
     let beneficiaryInfo = keys.indexOf(beneficiaryInfo);

     return this.personalInfo = {
            personalInfoId: 0,
            insurerInfo: {
               firstName:  this.data.calculatorInfo.name,
               lastName : this.data.calculatorInfo.surname,
               phoneNumber: this.data.contactInfo.phone,
               email: this.data.contactInfo.email
            },
            underageChildInfo: underageChildInfo!=-1 ?         this.data.underageChildInfo.map(i =>
              ({
              firstName: i.name,
              lastName: i.surname,
              birthDate: i.birthDate
            })) : null,
            beneficiaryInfo: beneficiaryInfo!=-1 ?
            this.data.beneficiaryInfo.map(i =>({
              firstName: i.name,
              lastName: i.surname
            })) : null
          }
       }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.info);
}
```

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21562659/can-i-write-an-if-statement-within-a-javascript-object-when-setting-an-attribute)